# What is the logic behind the solution to this algebra problem?

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, proof-explanation

I found this problem in "101 problems in Algebra" by Andreescu & Feng. I'm struggling to understand the provided solution and would appreciate if someone could help to explain the reasoning behind the various steps of their solution. The first step (setting up an equation in terms of x and solving for x) seems especially odd to me.

**Question**

Let $\left \{ \mathrm{a_{n}} \right \}_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence such that $\mathrm{a}_{1} = 2$ and  $\mathrm{a}_{n+1} = \frac{\mathrm{a}_{n}}{2}+\frac{1}{\mathrm{a}_{n}}$
$\text{ for all n} \in N.$

Find an explicit formula for $\mathrm{a}_{n}$

**Solution**

$\text{Solving the equation x =} \frac{x}{2}+\frac{1}{x}
\text{ leads to }
x = \pm \sqrt{2} 
\\
\\
\text{Note that:  }\\
\frac{\mathrm{a}_{n+1}+\sqrt{2}}{\mathrm{a}_{n+1}-\sqrt{2}} = \frac{\mathrm{a}_{n}^{2} + 2\sqrt{2}\mathrm{a}_{n}+2}{\mathrm{a}_{n}^{2} - 2\sqrt{2}\mathrm{a}_{n}+2} = \left(\frac{\mathrm{a}_{n}+\sqrt{2}}{\mathrm{a}_{n}-\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2}
\\
\\
\\
\text{Therefore:}\\
\frac{\mathrm{a}_{n}+\sqrt{2}}{\mathrm{a}_{n}-\sqrt{2}} = \left(\frac{\mathrm{a}_{1}+\sqrt{2}}{\mathrm{a}_{1}-\sqrt{2}}\right)^{2^{n-1}} = \left( \sqrt{2}+1 \right)^{2^{n}} 
\\
\\
\\
\text{and }\\ \mathrm{a}_{n}= \frac{\sqrt{2}\left[ \left(\sqrt{2}+1 \right)^{2^{n}}+1\right]}{\left(\sqrt{2}+1\right)^{2^{n}}-1}$

Comment: The idea behind the first step is that if the sequence $\left\{a_n\right\}_{n\ge1}$ defined by $a_{n+1}=\dfrac{a_n}2+\dfrac1{a_n}$ has a limit $x$, then $x=\dfrac x2+\dfrac 1x$

Comment: The question is: Can you follow that reasoning if you just accept the author is pulling stuff out of thin air that just happens to work?  Or do you want some understanding of how the author *thought* to do that weird stuff.  If we can just accept things out of thin air, we can ignore the first line.  The second *does* work.  We may not know where it's coming from or where it is going but it works.  The third line is just induction. And the result is algebra.  Is that enough? Or do you want to know *how* the heck he thought of all that weird stuff?

Comment: Thank you @fleablood Regarding the first step - is the idea that the sequence converges and reaches a limit where the next number in the sequence has to be equal to the previous one? I really would like to understand how the heck the author thought of doing this weird stuff! And how the first step connects with the rest of the solution.

Comment: Well as J.W. Tanner points out it's a standard trick that if you've got a recursive sequence $a_{n+1} =f(a_n)$ for some manipulation of $a_n$, and if you know the sequence converges then if $\lim_{n\to \infty} a_n= L$ we can find $L$ by noting that $n\to \infty$ is the same thing as $n+1\to \infty$ so $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_n=\lim_{n+1\to\infty}a_{n+1} = \lim_{n\to\infty}a_{n+1}=\lim_{n\to \infty}f(a_n) = f(L)$ and solving for $L$.  So the second line is  calculating $\frac{a_{n+1} +limit}{a_{n+1} -limit}$ but off the top of my head I'm not sure I see the inspiration of that.